# How to merge two array and assign each iteration a key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two array

```
arr1 = ["google.com", "none", "Twitter", "Facebook"]

arr2 = [6, 25, 1, 8]
```

Then my expected output would be like this

```
newArr = [
            {
                'medium': 'www.google.com',
                'key': 6
            },
            {
                'medium': 'none',
                'key': 25
            },
            {
                'medium': 'Twitter',
                'key': 1
            },
            {
                'medium': 'Facebook',
                'key': 8
            }
        ];
```

I have tried something like this but did not get the expected output

```
const result = arr1.reduce(function(result, field, index) {
            result[arr2[index]] = field;
            return result;
        });
```

How can I achieve the output? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a `map` with index

```js
const arr1 = ["google.com", "none", "Twitter", "Facebook"]
const arr2 = [6, 25, 1, 8]

const res = arr1.map((_, index) => ({
  medium: arr1[index],
  key: arr2[index],
}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: it does work. thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

This should work assuming arr1 and arr2 length always equal

```
function combineTwoArrays (arr1, arr2){
    let result = []
    for (let i = 0; i< arr1.length; i++){
       result.push({
           medium: arr1[i],
           key: arr2[i]
       })
    }
    return result
}
```